# Multivariate Normal Density. Integral Equation

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

can someone help me with this Question? 
$\\ $ 
Let $d \geq 2 $ and let $ f: \mathbb{R}^d \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ be a twice differentiable function. 
Let $ p(t,x)= \frac{1}{(2\pi t)^{\frac{d}{2}}} e^{\frac{- \vert \vert x \vert \vert ^2}{2t}} $  for $ (t,x) \in \mathbb{R}^d \times (0, \infty) $. 
Then $$ \int p(t,x) \frac{1}{2} \Delta f(x) dx = \int f(x) \frac{dp(t,x)}{dt} dx $$

I tried just to calculate the derivative and then put it into the Right side but this dosent work very well.
I know p(t,x) is just the multivariate normal Density for a $ N(0,t)$ Random variable but i dont know how to use it. 
Thanks for helping!!

Comment: Hint: The Gaussian $p(t,x)$ is a solution of the PDE $u_t=\frac{1}{2}\Delta u$. Then you can multiply the equation by your "test" $f$ and integrate by parts in $x$ twice.BTW the derivative on the right hand side should be partial. You need to assume something about the decay of $f$ at infinity for this to work formally.

Comment: thank you so much, your hint helped me alot! And u are Right, i forgot to write that f has a compact support.